# Allegro Throws errors when trying to draw lines

Tags: c++, allegro, allegro5

For some reason allegro (C++ Game Engine), throws errors when i try to run... So first this code works fine ! :

```
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_primitives.h>

int main(void)
{
    int width = 640, height = 480;
       ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = NULL;

    if (!al_init()) 
       return -1;


       display = al_create_display(width, height);


   if (!display) 
       return -1;


        al_flip_display();

        //al_draw_line(100, 100, width - 100, 100, al_map_rgb(255, 0, 0), 1);
        al_rest(3);


           al_destroy_display(display);
       return 0;
    }
```

But all the sudden when i try to uncomment that line above i get this "error".
[image]

More Closer Up:

[image]

As you can see above this is some type of assertion failling... Im Confused?! Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hmm... is this problem that hard?

Comment: No but a quick search of Google resulted in the answer being in the _first_ item of the result list. Maybe you should give it a try. Hint: You forgot to call something to initialize the add-on.

Comment: What did i forget @CaptainObvlious ... because if your method works.. ill feel very sorry i just deleted my allegro files and try to reinstall them back.

Comment: Hopefully deleting the allegro files won't be the only effort you put into _researching_ an answer.

Comment: Lol This @CaptainObvlious https://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/609086 ??

Answer (score 1):

Before you can use the primitives add-on you need to initialize it by calling [`al_init_primitives_addon`](https://www.allegro.cc/manual/5/al_init_primitives_addon).

```
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_primitives.h>

int main(void)
{
    int width = 640, height = 480;
    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = NULL;

    if (!al_init())
        return -1;


    display = al_create_display(width, height);

    if (!display)
        return -1;

    al_init_primitives_addon();

    if (!al_init_primitives_addon())
        return -1;

    al_draw_line(0, 50, 300, 100, al_map_rgb(255, 0, 4), 1.0f);

    al_flip_display();


    al_rest(13);


    al_shutdown_primitives_addon();

    al_destroy_display(display);
    return 0;
}
```

The full documentation can be found here: https://www.allegro.cc/manual/5/al_init_primitives_addon.

Don't forget to call [`al_shutdown_primitives_addon`](https://www.allegro.cc/manual/5/al_shutdown_primitives_addon) when you're done.

Comment: Ok But now i see only a black screen... ofcourse with the al_draw_line uncommented...

Comment: Probably a new question there, @Dsafds . Recommend a bit of document-reading first though. Might be something like a , "Yeah, I'm done updating the buffer. Put it on the screen, kay?" function call you need to make.

Comment: Ok Capitan. Do you have any tutorials you reccomend, because obviously i dont know where you are going here.. and im watching this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NkE4oFMu6VM&index=4&list=PL9333715188CD7669

Comment: No, I don't use Allegro and haven't used it in over a decade.

Comment: I got it @CaptainObvlious Thanks a lot ! Wait what you havent used Allegro? Well what  do you reccomend me to do after Allegro.

Comment: See liballeg.org for current versions of the documentation, not allegro.cc